# Read Excel file , store in MySQL database and perform crud operation on it

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on a Spring Boot application where users can upload Microsoft Excel files for editing. The challenge I'm facing is handling Excel files with a variable number of columns. Specifically, I need guidance on how to design the database schema to accommodate this variability without knowing the exact number of columns in advance and how can I store into  MySQL database .

So pls suggest me approach How can I store data into database without knowing the exact number of columns in excel file in advance ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please take the [tour], read [ask] and edit your question with this information.

Comment: *how to design the database schema to accommodate this variability without knowing the exact number of columns* EAV pattern. Serialized representation (CSV, JSON). Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the MySQL is not the right approach here (since you should have clear structure tables to be relational). You should look at no-sql databases for this such as Mongo or Dynamo.

If you still want MySQL the fast approach for this would be to save things as json, but then to do basic CRUD operations is a pain in the ass queries, and not so performant.